# ffplay on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I've gone through this - http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
I've gotten `FFMpeg` on Android, as in, my app is able to load the `FFMPeg` binary. However, `ffplay` commands do not work. Is it possible to port `ffplay` into my app?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this lib:

http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

FFmpeg4Android is a way your application can run FFmpeg commands,  only Java, no need for C code, or NDK.

You can use any player that supports streaming, on the target machine, to play the stream, in this case we used ffplay

```
ffplay -f mpegts -ast 1 -vst 0 -ar 48000 udp://192.168.0.114:8090
```

Comment: Yet to try out Ffmpeg4Android, but I'm wondering how you'd actually set a video source on the MediaPlayer class?

Comment: Anybody got an idea?

Comment: This not having ffplay included in the library, it has only ffmpeg