# Any solution for ffplay in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg, gopro

I'm trying to add GoPro (Hero) inside my app and I wanted to have live streaming to make my solution complete. Thanks to [KonradIT](https://github.com/konradit) who was committed to this task, I found most of what i need there. Anyway, my main concern is about live streaming. He has a [solution](https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-udp-stream-android) for this which is based on ffmpeg, but it has two main problems aside from some minor bug fixings. First, the output is not scalable and just shows a tiny picture which is not resizable. The other is its very low FPS (less than 17 FPS). We have a delay about six seconds too. 
On the PC side, we have a very simple solution using ffplay. It's just a line of code and works as one expected. But on Android, I have no clue how to use ffplay directly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004512/ffplay-on-android) some claimed that Android WarZone supports ffplay but as I've tested it, there's no support (in the Android WarZone page they just talked about ffplay on the PC side). So, to wrap things up, I've two problem:
1- Is there any solution for running ffplay in Android?
2- How can we convert its output to a live video?